# Requesting authorization for HealthKit isn't executed. (HKHealthStore().requestAuthorization)

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm currently trying to make a simple pedometer app.
However, I can't seem to get authorization working for using HealthKit.

I have this piece of code to try to get permission and use a callback afterward to process the result.

```
func authorizeHealthKit(withCallback: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> ())
{
    // 3. If the store is not available (for instance, iPad) return an error and don't go on.
    if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
        let error = NSError(domain: "health_tracker", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "HealthKit is not available in this Device"])
        print(error)
    }
    else {
        // 4.  Request HealthKit authorization
        self._healthKitStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: _healthKitTypesToWrite, read: _healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) -> Void in
            self.isAuthorized = success
            withCallback(success, error)
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, though, it seems that iOS is just completely skipping over that line. When setting a breakpoint on the callback function (that `authorizeHealthKit` calls), nothing happens and it doesn't stop. When using Step Over, it just skips those lines. The screen of my Simulator (and irl iPhone) are white and no dialogue pops up.

Any idea why this might happen?
Am I doing something wrong?

---

Additional info:

*In the same class (HealthKitManager.swift)*

```
let _healthKitStore: HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()
var isAuthorized: Bool = false
let _healthKitTypesToWrite: Set<HKSampleType> = [
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
]

let _healthKitTypesToRead: Set<HKSampleType> = [
    HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
]
```

*In another class, calling the above method:*

```
let _healthKitManager = HealthKitManager()
(...)
if !_healthKitManager.isAuthorized {
            _healthKitManager.authorizeHealthKit(withCallback: onAuthenticationResult)
        }
(...)
func onAuthenticationResult(success: Bool, error: Error?) {
    print("Authentication result: ", success.description)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me as well.
It was solved by upgrading my phone to iOS 11.3.1.
Please pay attention that it works smoothly on simulator even with a lower iOS, so i guess it's an xcode-bug, and upgrading to the newest xcode version could solve it as well...

Comment: Seems to be happening with XCode 10.1 and the companion simulator.  It now works (sort of) when I add a single step sample.  Health does crash on the simulator afterwards with a Watchdog error, but at least I get the requestAuthorizations screen.